# How to create a "Quick Shop" option in WooCommerce, similar to Urban Outfitters website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, e-commerce

I run an eCommerce website and the website owners want me to create a functionality on the site similar to the "Quick Shop" option on https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/womens-clothing.

When you are on the shop page and hover over a product and click on the "Quick Shop" button, a popup appears showing some options from the full product page, including Size/Color options. When you add the product to your cart in the quick shop popup and close out, you can keep shopping on the page you were on much faster.

I have looked at various plugin options and haven't found one that works exactly the same.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect tool at https://iconicwp.com/products/woocommerce-quickview/. This solved my problem.